# Teradata pypyodbc SQL_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc, python-2.6, pypyodbc

While connecting **pypyodbc** with teradata i am getting SQL_INVALID_HANDLE

OS - Red Hat  4.4.7-17

Python Version - 2.6.6

I am not having administrative privilages to install the pypyodbc so i have downloaded the module, set pythonpath and imported it.

Done the required exports to point the python module to find the correct libodbc.so

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/teradata/client/15.10/odbc_64/lib/
export ODBCINST=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbcinst.ini
export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/odbc.ini
```

used the below code to create a db connection

```
pypyodbc.connect("Driver={Teradata};DBCNAME=<DB>;UID=<UNAME>;PWD=<PASS>")
```

The odbc connection string i have used is correct. I have tested using the below approach

```
/opt/teradata/client/15.10/bin/tdxodbc64 -C "Driver={Teradata};DBCNAME=<DB>;UID=<UNAME>;PWD=<PASS>"
```

**Note:**I am not using teradata OOTB python module because it works with a higher version of python which i cannot install.

Error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<LOCAL_PATH>/pypyodbc.py", line 2421, in __init__
    AllocateEnv()
  File "<LOCAL_PATH>/pypyodbc.py", line 1000, in AllocateEnv
    check_success(SQL_NULL_HANDLE, ret)
  File "<LOCAL_PATH>/pypyodbc.py", line 990, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, ODBC_obj, ret, False)
  File "<LOCAL_PATH>/pypyodbc.py", line 970, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError('', 'SQL_INVALID_HANDLE')
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('', 'SQL_INVALID_HANDLE')
```

any guidance on the matter is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some packages. You can use this command:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel libtool-ltdl libtool-ltdl-devel
```

This wiki will help you.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki